# Android 6 android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE allow on install

Tags: android-6.0-marshmallow, user-permissions

I'm using Android 6 with target SDK 23. 
I need to accept one permission(**READ_PHONE_STATE**) on install, like it was before target SDK 23, in google store it shows you permission and you accept it, then app will be installed.

I **don't** want to use a popup. I need to you use target SDK 23 but without popup of permissions. You will say - **it's impossible!** But, maybe anybody knows how?

P.S. Normally it should be some flag in AndroidManifest or gradle...

P.S.S : Should be like that below

[image: Should be like that]

And **not** like that below :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

if you want that no pop up will be shown or directly setup permissions then you have to do like this:

http://www.howtogeek.com/230683/how-to-manage-app-permissions-on-android-6.0/

Comment: thanks for help, but this link just saying one more time that this is impossible.